# update status input radio button jstl and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

i am using spring mvc

when i am creating user, in my form active or deactive radio button is perfectly saving in my db

when i am editing my user its not selecting actual status in input radio button, i need suggestions in jslt, below is my code

```
<div class="section">
    <label>Status<small>status</small></label>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="radio-1" value="ACTIVE" class="ck" checked='<c:out value="${userIdSearch.state ? 'ACTIVE'}">checked</c:out>'/> 
       <label for="radio-1">Active</label>

       <input type="radio" name="status" id="radio-2" value="DEACTIVE" class="ck" checked='<c:out value="${userIdSearch.state ? 'DEACTIVE'}">checked</c:out>'/> 
       <label for="radio-2">Deactive</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance pradeep

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about this. i hope my answer can help u. just try it out.

```
<input checked="<c:if test="${userIdSearch eq 'Active'}">checked</c:if>">
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be putting the attribute inside the EL expression, in a ternary if; if the condition is true, put the attribute checked=checked; if not, do nothing

```
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="radio-1" value="ACTIVE" class="ck" ${userIdSearch.state eq 'ACTIVE' ? 'checked=\"checked\"' :''} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Import java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt (I call it "c", but you can call it whatever):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
```

Then you can use the c:if in the radio button like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="radio-1" value="ACTIVE" class="ck" <c:if test="${status.value == 'ACTIVE'}">checked="checked"</c:if> />Active
```

If this is still not binding to your object, you could try using spring binding like so:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
...
<spring:bind path="pathToActive.status">
    <input type="radio" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" id="radio-1" ... etc
</spring:bind>
```